# OneDrive for Business: High CPU, memory and disk loads

Tags: cpu-usage, onedrive

I downloaded OneDrive for Business to my personal computer yesterday and is working fine, except for very high CPU, memory, and disk loads:
[image: Screenshot]

- **Left Screenshot:** When syncing new files via OneDrive, even a small folder with a few files totaling ~5MB in size, the CPU, memory, and disk loads increases significantly due to *Microsoft OneDrive for Business (32 bit)* and *Microsoft Office Document Cache (32 bit)* (left screenshot).
- **Right Screenshot:** When I open `%UserProfile%\OneDrive` after syncing, *Microsoft OneDrive for Business (32 bit)* starts using both CPU and memory, and when all folders, except three, have a checkmark, the CPU and memory loads are reduced to more acceptable levels.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `OneDrive for Business` client installed when you have the non-Business service?  Your running the wrong OneDrive client.  `OneDrive for Business` uses SharePoint on the backend, the Office 365 service your subscribed to, does not.

Comment: @Ramhound: Because that is what I have been told to do by the university. I'm not using my private mail, but my student mail (username@win.ntnu.no).

Comment: I still believe you to be using the incorrect client.  But honestly its this is a known problem with `OneDrive for Business` because the backend and the fact the sync engine is slightly different then the integrated OneDrive client in Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 desktop client.

Comment: Okay. On the university's wiki it says: 

"Please note that many versions of Windows 7 and newer have a version of OneDrive installed. This one will not work with your NTNU account. Please be certain to use "OneDrive for Business", which is downloaded together with Office 365, or else you will not be able to sign in." (translated)

I guess I will have to talk to University IT. Or is is no point, seeing that it is a well-known problem?

Comment: There isn't anything that can done by your IT department.  Is it perhaps the amount of data in these folders?

Comment: @Ramhound: 23.1 GB, 9121 files, 1165 folders.

Comment: If you have lots of large files your high usage is caused by that.  As I pointed out the sync client is slightly different.

Comment: Well, and that OneDrive is poorly written software compared to Dropbox. I can confirm high CPU load is common with OneDrive. It is not smart about knowing what files changed since last time without a full file scan it seems.

Comment: OneDrive for Business, I confirm, is correct for many University environments that offer Office365 email/OneDrive/Office365. We've just deployed it to all our students and the Business app is the one to use because the business OneDrive is a SharePoint back-end, as opposed to the normal client. I wonder if the high resource utilisation is linked to indexing and the meta data being produced to populate OneDrive on the servers...?

Comment: You can’t do anything. OneDrive for Business was not designed to be used for anything more than very trivial file storage, the fact that MS offers large amounts of space in SharePoint is basically pointless because of how horrible the client is and how restrictive SharePoint is on how files may be named.

Answer (score 1):

High CPU usage comes from calculating differentials between files in your local store and cloud. Some example of this kind of algorithm you can see [here](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octodiff). Quoting:

> Of course, the benefit is that instead of transferring the entire new file to machine A, we just transfer a small signature, and a delta file containing the differences. We're trading off CPU usage for potentially large bandwidth savings.

To save you from downloading whole file every single time, they calculate 'delta file' which is then send to server. I can't provide you every detail of this operation in case of OneDrive because there are many problems to solve in this kind of operation in cloud synchronization. But you can be sure they don't want to send whole file every time you change it, so they're using your CPU to minimize amount of data to send/receive.

Increased usage of memory is also normal, because every single programs needs memory to keep its data while running. So whenever it's working on a file (a block of data) it must load it to memory. Those are basics of every programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to download One Drive files onto a new Celeron laptop.

One Drive was using 40-63% CPU, and for every 1cm I moved my mouse, the cursor would move 5cm.

I ended up shutting One Drive down, and copying One Drive files from my desktop onto laptop over the LAN.

Another solution if you don't have LAN access is to copy the files onto USB thumb or HDD, and copy them onto your new computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue of continual high CPU usage from OneDrive on Win10 1703 (early Creators version).  I upgraded to Win10 1709 (latest Creators version).  This comes with an updated OneDrive client, that once pointed to my local mirrored files, overrode the old OneDrive client, and fixed the issue.

Note I needed to run a registry command from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-users-to-sync-SharePoint-files-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-22e1f635-fb89-49e0-a176-edab26f69614, "Test the feature before you enable it" heading.

The new OneDrive client seems to be better at keeping in sync, and contains an option to only download the online files you edit.

Cheers.

Comment: You don’t need to upgrade windows to upgrade the one drive client. The latest version of the unified client can be downloaded from onedrive.com. It also automatically updates itself under most circumstances. This is an old thread and probably references the old OneDrive for Business client which is on its way out.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

- My OneDrive server is behind my company firewall, so when I am working remotely, and if the VPN is not on, then high CPU may result, so connecting to the VPN can help; but just that alone may not be enough
- There might be some issues that have accumulated since the last successful VPN connection, so I may also need to go clear the issues (click the little OneDrive icon and click the appropriate buttons to retry sync and so on)

Hope this helps somebody else too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by deleting the node_modules folders in a few NodeJS projects I had stored and built on my OneDrive. These compilations download a LOT of files (I had projects with more than 35000 files in node_modules) and they seem to cause OneDrive to start using a LOT of cpu and memory. After identifying the folders with large numbers of files using TreesizeFree (https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free), I deleted them using the web ui of OneDrive and after the desktop client finished syncing (this may take a while), its cpu and memory usage came down to normal levels.
I hope this helps you solve your issues. Btw, I'm running Windows 10 v2004 and the latest insider build of OneDrive.

Answer (score -1):

[Try turning off Indexing](http://www.lauramartin.co.nz/fix-one-drive-causing-high-memory-usage/). I've just done that  for one of my Service Desk clients and it has reduced memory usage by 20%.

I've got instructions on my blog. But basically you go to Control Panel and turn off indexing there.

Good luck.

Comment: Turning off indexing will prevent the Start Menu from finding things. This action shouldn’t be necessary and is probably just a shortcoming of the OneDrive for Business client…

Comment: It won't prevent you find things in Start Menu. It will only cause your searches be much slower than usual. But if you're using searches rarely, you can definitely disable it. I usually disable it for my system drive, to increase performance of OS.